# What is the best way to back-up the Linux kernel before performing a kernel and device tree update?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

Is this as simple as duplicating the directory /boot to /boot~ before using dpkg to apply the updated Kernel ?

So if the systems is bricked then all I would need to do is put the SD card into another system, erase the upgraded /boot directory and rename /boot~ back to /boot?

If not, does anyone know how best to back-up the entire Kernel before applying a kernel update complied from the sources available on kernel.org ?

Yesterday upgrading from 5.15.27 to 5.15.28 bricked by embedded controller. I've since got it working, but from a clean pre-built 5.15.27 image. Currently copying my customisations from SD card containing bricked system to the now working system.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Timeshift`.

Best tool for backup/restore of the OS. It can revert any changes you did to the OS. As long as you can boot up the machine - no problem.

For changes in kernel, I would recommend to prepare a LiveCD/USB, and running timeshift restore from it - solves even a badly compiled kernel.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a system on a board.
https://web.archive.org/web/20220317161539/http://www.lemaker.org/product-bananapro-specification.html

The next question is if I create a bootable USB, how the heck do I use the U-Boot commands to start-up an OS off the USB?

I know....  There is the option ot take the SD card out and make a sector-by-sector backup.  Will have to try that, but when I restored a sector-by-sector backup created using EaseUS ToDO Backup, the kernel failed to start.  :-(

Will have to try again with another card to see if it was just a bad luck blip.